# move list items between unordered list sets while maintaining position order

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this code sample ([source](http://jsbin.com/izuwe/2/edit)) to add list items (item 1, item 2 etc) to a master list from a set of unordered lists (list1, list2). On removing list items from the master list, they have to go back to the original position in the unordered list where it came from.

The code in the sample works randomly; sometimes the list items are arranged in sequential order but at other times they may not be in order. I need help in fixing the code so that when items are moved from the master list, they are arranged in sequential order in the originating unordered list.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the code and made use of the .data function..i guess the code is much cleaner now. [My new revision](http://jsfiddle.net/ifaour/NYS7N/).

Would this do the job for you?

Comment: Thanks for your sample! While this looks neater & better than the original, the items do not show up in sorted order in random instances. To reproduce, try moving item 6 from the master list in the sample & right after that move item 5. The sequence in the originating list goes for a toss. This seems to happen only for the second list &  item 5 seems to be the culprit.

Comment: Ah sorry about that, just changed/corrected the initial iteration on the LIs: http://jsfiddle.net/ifaour/NYS7N/1/

Comment: Please have a look at mvark sample and if you don't mind adding IDs for all your LIs and hiding them, then it's a great approach too!

Answer (score 0):

Check [my sample](http://jsbin.com/adero3).

This is what I'm doing -
When a list item from any list is clicked, that list item is hidden & its clone is added to the master list to simulate moving the item. When the cloned list item in the master list is clicked, that item is removed & the clone's parent is shown back again with the show() method.